# focusout and blur not working in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to detect when the user clicks off the div. I added this code in `component.html`

```
  <div class="h unselected" contenteditable="false" (mousedown)="mousedown($event)" (mouseup)="mouseup($event)" (focusout)="focusout($event)" (blur)="focusout($event)">
    Hello
  </div>
```

component.ts has focusout(e) implemented (among other things)

```
focusout(e){
    console.log("f out");
  }
```

The method never gets fired when I click outside of the `Hello div`. Why is that?  I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `tabindex` on the div. The [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) indicates if its element can be focused.

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="h unselected" contenteditable="false" (mousedown)="mousedown($event)" (mouseup)="mouseup($event)" (focusout)="focusout($event)" (blur)="focusout($event)">
    Hello
  </div>
```

**Why `-1`?**

According to the mozilla web docs:

> A negative value (usually tabindex="-1") means that the element should
>   be focusable, but should not be reachable via sequential keyboard
>   navigation. Mostly useful to create accessible widgets with
>   JavaScript.
>
> tabindex="0" means that the element should be focusable in sequential
>   keyboard navigation, but its order is defined by the document's source
>   order.
>
> A positive value means the element should be focusable in sequential
>   keyboard navigation, with its order defined by the value of the
>   number. That is, tabindex="4" would be focused before tabindex="5",
>   but after tabindex="3". If multiple elements share the same positive
>   tabindex value, their order relative to each other follows their
>   position in the document source.

Answer (score 3):

Not all elements support focusing by default. `div` is one of them.

**Any element can support focusing if it has `tabIndex` attribute.**

So i would try:

```html
<div tabindex="-1" ...></div
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jMOsFiW6rry7DWseZ6EN?p=preview)**

See more details about `tabindex` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex