# Angular 2 How to blur input on button return?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to blur `input` by pressing native keyboard return `button` on mobile ?

For example :

```
<input type="text" #search>

this.search.blur() //-- unfocus and hide keyboard
```

Comment: Expected output will be more clear... that means how do you want!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**html file**

```
<input type="text"  #search (keyup.enter)="doSomething()">
```

**.ts file**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

  @ViewChild('search') search: ElementRef;

  doSomething(): void {
    this.search.nativeElement.blur()
  }
```

working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k7btgk)

Comment: how to test it in browser not in a phone ?

Comment: you can access the site via mobile phone, I tested it is working

Comment: I am using this method right now, but it actually working only when I call it in next tick.
```setTimeout(() => this.btcField.nativeElement.blur(), 0);```
I am sure it must be better method to do this in the same tick.
For example in the end of bubbling events.
Any Idea how to do this?
I am not familiar with angular 2 good enough yet.
I am bluring input inside click event.
There is small button for scan qrcode, and I want to hide keyboard on mobile, when user clicks it.

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding of the problem, Ebin's code should be sufficient. For the sake of completeness and in case someone else stumbles onto this post and just needs something really simple though, this should work as well.

If the overall intent is simply to blur an input on a key (or some other simple binding) and then do/emulate another action with the elements, then there is not a need to use ViewChild decorators or the additional method in the component.

Building off Ebin's code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" #search (keyup.enter)="search.blur(); clickButton.click()">
<button #clickButton (click)="buttonClicked()" type="button">Hello</button>
```

**.ts**

```
buttonClicked() {
// do something
}
```

Here's a working stackblitz, again built off of Ebin's answer: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1a67ua)

In this instance, the element references are still used, just template-side. Alternatively instead of calling clickButton.click(), the method call to buttonClicked() could also be assigned here, though this might be dependent on intended behavior.

If the real case is more complex, then you would still likely want to implement Ebin's solution in order to keep logic where logic belongs. But if it is as simple as blur on keyup and then do another thing, you can use the references in the template itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keyup.<key>` event to do so.
To set blur, you can use the tabindex attribute, for more info, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391662/focusout-and-blur-not-working-in-angular) link

Example

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" tabindex="focus" #search (keyup.enter)="doSomething()">
```

**.ts**

```
doSomething(): void {
    this.focus = -1;
}
```

Comment: My question was how to blur - this.search.blur() won't blur input.

Comment: Edited answer. @Angulandy2

Comment: what is focus equal before ?

Comment: It will be 0 @Angulandy2

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="text" #search (keyup.enter)="doSomething()">


     doSomething(): void {
       document.getElementById("search").blur();
    }
```